# Set system tray notifyicon.icon to a pic in images folder

Tags: c#, image, notifyicon

I've tried several things and eventualy just put the image directly inside C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FolderMonitor\FolderMonitor\bin\Debug. This works for now, but idealy I'd like to set the notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon("folder.ico") to an image inside a images folder in the solution. But I can't figure out how this works..

```
    public FolderMonitorApplicationContext()
    {
        this.monitor =  new Monitor();

        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon("folder.ico");
        notifyIcon.Text = "Folder Monitor";
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

        contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        openMonitor = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        exitApplication = new ToolStripMenuItem();

        notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu;

        notifyIcon.DoubleClick += NotifyIcon_DoubleClick;

        openMonitor.Text = "Open";
        openMonitor.Click += new EventHandler(OpenMonitor_Click);
        contextMenu.Items.Add(openMonitor);

        exitApplication.Text = "Exit..";
        exitApplication.Click += new EventHandler(ExitApplication_Click);
        contextMenu.Items.Add(exitApplication);
    }
```

So it's currently working, but not how it i'd like it to work. Hope you can help me out here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Project + Properties, Resources tab.  Add your icon there.  In your code you can now simply use Properties.Resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the picture file to your project, bring up the item properties by clicking on it, and pressing F4.  Under Build Action, change it to "Embedded Resource".

You can access embedded resources in `Stream` form like this:

```
public FolderMonitorApplicationContext()
{
    this.monitor =  new Monitor();

    notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
        "<project namespace>.<folder path>" + "filename.ico"))
    {
        notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon(stream);
    }

    notifyIcon.Text = "Folder Monitor";
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;

    contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    openMonitor = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    exitApplication = new ToolStripMenuItem();

    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu;

    notifyIcon.DoubleClick += NotifyIcon_DoubleClick;

    openMonitor.Text = "Open";
    openMonitor.Click += new EventHandler(OpenMonitor_Click);
    contextMenu.Items.Add(openMonitor);

    exitApplication.Text = "Exit..";
    exitApplication.Click += new EventHandler(ExitApplication_Click);
    contextMenu.Items.Add(exitApplication);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!:) I've tried this before but forgot to change the property on the image..

Comment: You can shorten that to `notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon(this.GetType(), "folder.ico");`

Comment: @Idle_Mind This works only if folder.ico stays next to .cs file, in the same folder. However, people in general tend to put these icons into a Resources/Images folder to keep things organized, not next to CS files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same method to insert the icon on the form.
To find the same code in your application to copy in your systemtray please:

1. check if, in the file .resx, there is the icon called with $ symbol(example:"$this.icon")
2. find your code to include the icon on the [name of form].desiner.cs.

example of code in my application:

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(systemtray));

trayIcon.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```